# Why the following expression is evaluated to true?

Tags: php

I want to know why the following expression is evaluated to true.

```
var_dump(('a' == 0)); //bool(true)
```

Comment: Do a `echo (int) 'a';` and you will understand better.

Comment: when strings are compared with integers, they are automatically casted as integer, and if they don't contain a number, the result of that casting is 0. and `0 == 0` - that's why you never compare a string with an integer - and if you have to, you use the strict comparison: `'a' === 0` is false.

Answer (score 6):

[String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) (from the PHP manual, emphasis mine)

> When a string is evaluated in a numeric context, the resulting value
>   and type are determined as follows.
>
> If the string does not contain any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E'
>   and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by
>   PHP_INT_MAX), the string will be evaluated as an integer. In all other
>   cases it will be evaluated as a float.
>
> **The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string
>   starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used.
>   Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).** Valid numeric data is an
>   optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a
>   decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an
>   'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.

Examples :

```
var_dump(('a' == 0)); //bool(true)
var_dump(('a' === 0)); //bool(false)
var_dump(('aaaa' == 0)); //bool(true)
var_dump(('1aaaa' == 1)); //bool(true)
var_dump(('18aaaaa' == 18)); //bool(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

you may expect this

```
<?php
var_dump('a' === 0);
```

https://eval.in/667364

Comment: No, i know the difference between "==" and "===".  Thanks, anyway!